# How to send hotkey self when hotkey doesn't qualify in autohotkey2

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I want to send the hot when the conditions are met, and send the hotkey itself when none of the conditions are met,like this:

```
^p:: {
    appName := GetappName()
    switch appName {
        case "Code":
            Send "^+p"
        default:
            Send "^p"
    }
    return
}

^n:: {
    appName := GetappName()
    switch appName {
        case "Obsidian":
            Send "!n"
        case "Code":
            Send "^!#n"
        default:
            Send "^n"
    }
    return
}
```

How is this code in default?

Comment: You want to forget about that switch case and use [`#HotIf`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_HotIf.htm).

Comment: I tried using #HOTIF but it didn't work,sorry i'm newbird
```ahk
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe Code.exe")
^n::^!#n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved, it can be used by switching back to #hotif, it didn't work because I swapped ctrl and caps with powertoys,now i can use $ or #hotif ,thanks